# How to determine if .NET Core Runtime is installed from CentOs 7

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, runtime, centos7

One knows how to check if the `.net core SDK` is installed or not (you need `dotnet --version` or `where dotnet`). How about `.net core runtime` as well as the `aspnet core runtime`?

PS: since in production we don't need the `.net Core SDK`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dotnet --info` will show the version of the SDK (if installed), the names and versions of all the runtimes that are installed, including the .NET Core runtime and ASP.NET Core runtime.

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.301
 Commit:    59524873d6

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     fedora
 OS Version:  28
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         fedora.28-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.1
  Commit:  N/A

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.301 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

If you only care about the runtime (.NET Core and ASP.NET Core) versions, you can use `dotnet --list-runtimes`. This requires a recent-enough version of .NET Core:

```
$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I don't have the ASP.NET Core runtime packages installed, so it only shows me the .NET Core runtime.

Comment: And failure to even run that command would indicate that .NET core isn't even present.

Comment: Yup! `dotnet --version` requires the SDK, so it will fail on runtime-only installs. But `dotnet --info` works everywhere.